# What is PIG_HOME, PIG_INSTALL in a cloudera installation?

Tags: linux, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I'm running "Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.3.0".

Because of this issue ([Pig ORDER command fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983956/pig-order-command-fails)) I've been told to set my pig_home or pig_install.

However, I can't figure out where the pig home folder would be when installed through cloudera?

I'm on a ubuntu system (if that help).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your installation method and possibly the OS itself, but look under `/usr/lib/pig/`.